# Unable to Submit form with multiple div id ...? please help me

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Unable to submit form with multiple div id, when i have only one div id form is submitting correctly when i use more than one div id form is not submitting. I want to show the new fields when a radio button is pressed, for the purpose of hiding and visbility i used div id(four div id with different id names) please help

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Report Generation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="../css/formstyle.css">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function setVisible(id, visible) {
        var o = document.getElementById(id);
        if (typeof(o) != 'undefined') o.style.visibility = visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        if (typeof(o) == 'undefined') alert("Element with id '" + id + "' not found.");
    }

    function setDisplay(id, visible) {
        var o = document.getElementById(id);
        if (typeof(o) != 'undefined') o.style.display = visible ? 'block' : 'none';
        if (typeof(o) == 'undefined') alert("Element with id '" + id + "' not found.");
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body   onLoad="setVisible('Div4', false); setVisible('Div1', false);setVisible('Div3', false);setVisible('Div2', false);">
<form class="reg_form" action="pr.php" method="post" name="reg_form">

<ul>
    <li>
        <p>What type of Report you want to Create ?</p><br/>
     </li> 
     <li>
        <input type='radio' name='myradio' value='1' onclick="setVisible('Div1', true); setVisible('Div2', false);setVisible('Div3', false);setVisible('Div4', false);" />Based on Date<br/>
        <input type='radio' name='myradio' value='2' onclick="setVisible('Div2', true); setVisible('Div1', false);setVisible('Div3', false);setVisible('Div4', false);"  />Based on Income<br/>
        <input type='radio' name='myradio' value='3' onclick="setVisible('Div3', true); setVisible('Div1', false);setVisible('Div2', false);setVisible('Div4', false);" />Based on District<br/>
        <input type='radio' name='myradio' value='4' onclick="setVisible('Div4', true); setVisible('Div1', false);setVisible('Div3', false);setVisible('Div2', false);" />Based on Age<br/>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div id='Div1'>

                        <p>From Date:</p> <input type="date" name= "from" required><br/>
                        <p>To Date:</p> <input type="date" name= "to" required><br/>

    </div>
    </li>
    <li>

    <div id='Div2'>
                        <p>Select Slab:</p>
                        <input type="radio" name="slab" value="s1">Slab-1<br/>  
                        <input type="radio" name="slab" value="s2">Slab-2<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="slab" value="s3">Slab-3<br/>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div id='Div3'>
                        <p>Enter District:</p><br/>   
                        <input type="text" name= "dist" required>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div id='Div4'>
                        <p>Select Age From:</p><br/>     
                        <input type="number" name= "afrom" required>
                        <p>To:</p>      
                        <input type="number" name= "ato" required>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
    </li>
</ul>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by multiple div id's? I can see that your div's have unique id's; so I don't see there's a problem with this...

Comment: What do you mean by not submitting properly - is there an error?

Comment: I tested your code, it sends all data correctly..., however, I removed all `required=""` attribute :)

Comment: no the file pr.php is not even called... when deleted 3 div ids and used only one , the pr.php is called. but the current form does not even call pr.php

Comment: Your input elements are not well formed in that they are not closed correctly - also you have a closing </div> tag after the closing </ul>.

Comment: the "required"  was the problem..

Comment: @ChrisMoutray, are you referring to the `input`s not closing `/>`? That's only required for `XHTML`.

Comment: @MichaelRushton yes - I think its still good practice to ensure all tags are well formed

Comment: It *is* well-formed. The `/` is entirely *optional*. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element - and there's no mention that it's *better* to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have `required` attributes on hidden input fields. When the form is submitted with these fields hidden (and them having no value), you're getting the errors:

```
An invalid form control with name='from' is not focusable.
An invalid form control with name='to' is not focusable.
An invalid form control with name='dist' is not focusable.
An invalid form control with name='afrom' is not focusable.
An invalid form control with name='ato' is not focusable.
```

By showing all the fields, or removing the `required` attributes, the form submits fine. A solution to this is to add the `required` attribute when shown and remove it when hidden.

To achieve this, firstly, define the following function:

```
function setRequired()
{

  var r = document.getElementsByClassName('required')

  for (var i in r)
  {

    if (r[i].parentNode && r[i].parentNode.style.visibility == 'visible')
    {
      r[i].required = true
    }

    else
    {
      r[i].required = false
    }

  }

}
```

Secondly, replace all `required` attributes with `class="required"`. And thirdly, add `;setRequired()` to the `onclick` events of the four radio buttons (at the end, after the `setVisible`s).

Comment: thanks it worked and how to add and remove "required" as u said? i have bo idea so only asking. please help me bro...

Answer (score 0):

change:

`<button class="submit" type="submit">Submit Form</button>`

to:

`<input type="submit">Submit Form</input>`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using <button type='submit'>Submit Form</button> and it is not the cause of the problem.